# AutoIt: Browser authentication issue on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, autoit

In my test environment, the authentication is done using a windows popup whereas in production its done normally i.e everything is on the webpage.

I am using AutoIT but none of scripts are working, please help.

Few of the solution that I tried,

```
WinWaitActive("Authentication Required","","10")
Send("username")
Send("{TAB}")
Send("password")
Send("{Enter}")
```

2nd solution:

```
WinWait("locator","","10") // where locator is class found by using Finder tool 
 If WinExists("locator","") Then // in AutoIT
 WinActivate("locator") 
 Send("username@domain.com{TAB}")
 WinActivate("locator")
 Send("password{ENTER}") 
 EndIf
```

I know that this seems pretty straight forward but i have not been able to this on chrome whereas if i tweak the script a bit it works fine on IE

Comment: Can somebody please show me how enter data into this url's popup (should work on chrome), http://engprod-charter.net/

Comment: Did you try url authorization? http://username:password@engprod-charter.net

Comment: Yes i did try but its not working

Answer (score 0):

on selenium for handling browser authentication pop up all you need to do;

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("username", "password");
alert.Accept();
```

Comment: besides this is still in beta

Comment: I really don't know anything abt AutoIt but that is the way you handle in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

For automation Google Chrome you can use [Chrome UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/).
There are 3 steps of installation:

1. Install the AutoIT [extension](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_6JmwNIIZ06enotRTVFNVdKOXM/edit?usp=sharing) into Chrome
2. Install the AutoIT [Chrome Native Messaging Host](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_6JmwNIIZ06eDgxaVJPNUNxa28/edit?usp=sharing)
3. Install the [Chrome UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=42015) into AutoIT

[Here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154439-chrome-udf/?do=findComment&comment=1327885) is some details if you have any problem with extension.

Example of usage:

```
#Include <Chrome.au3>

$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"

_ChromeStartup("https://yoururl.com")       ; start web page in Chrome
sleep(1000)
_ChromeObjSetValueByName("FIELD_USER_ID", $Username)        ; set username field
sleep(1000)
_ChromeObjSetValueByName("FIELD_PASSWORD", $Password)       ; set password field

_ChromeInputClickByName("login")  ; name of "Login" button
```

IDs of fields and buttons you can get from source code of web page (F12 in Chrome).

Also you can try to use http url authorization:

```
_ChromeStartup("http://" & $username & ":" & $password & "@" & "engprod-charter.net/")
```

Comment: Somehow the first solution that i posted is working now, anyways thanks guys